# Jmeter: How to get combined thread count from multiple jmeter slaves

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am using jmeter distributed environment and distributing load on multiple slave machine. I am running `jmeter -g <csv file> -o <output folder>` command to get html report from output csv file.

In report `Time Vs Threads` graph shows only one slave machines thread count instead of combined thread count on x axis.

e.g. if my slave 1 and slave 2 running 10 thread each but generated graph shows 10 number of active thread on X axis but it should be 20.

Answer (score 0):

As per current [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html):

> In distributed mode, this graph shows a horizontal axis the number of threads for 1 server. It's a current limitation

[image]

---

You can use [Response Times vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) plugin as the alternative solution, it can be installed as a part of **KPI vs KPI Graphs** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]